# relation between universal references and interfaces

Tags: c++11

I am reading scott meyers book on effective modern C++ in Item 27 following is tex

> In using universal reference parameter, in complex system universal
>   reference is forwarded thourgh several layers of function calls before
>   finally arriving at a site that determines whether the argument
>   type(s) are acceptable. The more times the universal reference is
>   forwarded, the mor ebaffling the error message may be when something
>   goes wrong. Many developers find that this issue alone is grounds to
>   reserve universal reference parameters for interfaces where
>   performance is foremost concern.

Some back ground at link

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rjhIBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=universal+reference+parameters+vs+interfaces&source=bl&ots=Fl0OZ6zCsR&sig=1qtsPv44aUl91B8SNcSYWswqSD0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpgOj2janJAhWK8CYKHY2DDd0Q6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=universal%20reference%20parameters%20vs%20interfaces&f=false

I am following question from above text

1. What does author mean by "reserve universal reference parameters for interfaces" ?
2. Is there any relation between universal reference and interfaces in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be interpreting common English as technical terms. The sentence in question is this:

> Many developers find that this issue alone is grounds to reserve universal reference parameters for interfaces where performance is foremost concern.

"Universal reference" (now known as "forwarding reference") is a technical term, but the other words are used in their normal programmer's English meaning. The sentence could be re-phrased in simpler words like this:

> Many developers find that because of this issue, they only use universal references in the parameters of a function if performace of the function is crucial.

To answer your exact questions:

1. Because of the potentially cryptic error messages, developers decide to only use universal references for certain interfaces. In other words, they *reserve* them for these interfaces.
2. The word "interface" is used as "the point in which you access something." A function, a class, or something similar. It's not an `interface` as the technical term in the object-oriented sense. C++ doesn't even have a notion of such an "`interface`".

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIU, he means "avoid using universal references excessively widely, use them mostly in (public) APIs or in interfaces between large architectural components".
2. Using universal references, on one hand, is efficient (objects are moved when possible, copied otherwise) and, on the other hand, lets you get rid of multiple overloaded methods. For these reasons, universal references are useful in API design.

When designing a class that is *neither* an interface *nor* part of an API, you as a programmer have the choice between using universal references

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T&&);
```

and overloading

```
void Foo(Foo&&);
void Foo(const Foo&)
void Foo(Bar&&);
void Foo(const Bar&);
// overloads with volatile are less commonly used, but possible
```

The first option is more concise. The second one produces clearer messages in case of compilation errors.

You also have the option of doing without some of the overloads. But that may be less efficient (in terms of performance) a solution.

Comment: Don't forget that universal references capture `volatile` as well.